# How to convert object[] to char[] in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, object, char, hashset

Is there a way to convert object[] to char[] ?

```
HashSet<Character> set = new HashSet<>();
...
// Can the set of characters be converted to char array something like below?
// char[] letters = set.toArray(new char[set.size()]);
```

Comment: probably not to char, but to Character for sure (automatically)... you should probably have a look to streams, and map the Characters to char

Answer (score 1):

> How to convert object[] to char[] in Java?

It doesn't get more straight forward than this.

```
Object[] s = { 'a', 'b', 'c' };
char[] arr = new char[s.length];
for (int i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
    arr[i] = (char)s[i];
}
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
```

Prints

```
[a, b, c]
```

For the set situation, a similar approach may be taken.

```
set.add('x');
set.add('y');
set.add('z');

char[] arr = new char[set.size()];
int i = 0;
for (Character c : set) {
    arr[i++] = c.charValue();
}
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
```

Prints

```
[x, y, z]
```

Or a streamed version.

```
char[] arr = set.stream().map(c -> Character.toString((char) c))
        .collect(Collectors.joining()).toCharArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the toArray() method with a cast to `Character[]`, and then copy the elements to a `char[]` (you cannot cast `Character[]` directly to `char[]`) :

```java
HashSet<Character> set = new HashSet<>();
Character[] cLetters = (Character[]) set.toArray();
char[] letters = new char[cLetters.length];
// copy the values
for (int i = 0; i < cLetters.length; i++) {
    letters[i] = cLetters[i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If `Object` is `Character`

```
HashSet<Character> set = new HashSet<>();
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
set.forEach(sb::append);
char[] letters = sb.toString().toCharArray();
```